# How to encode and decode data in base64 and base64URL by using unix commands?

Tags: shell, encoding, base64, decoding, base64url

Base64 encode can be achieved by

```
$ echo Some_data_to_be_converted | base64

U29tZV9kYXRhX3RvX2JlIF9jb252ZXJ0ZWQK
```

And Base64 decode can be achieved by

```
$ echo U29tZV9kYXRhX3RvX2JlIF9jb252ZXJ0ZWQK | base64 -d

Some_data_to_be_converted
```

1. How to achieve Base64URL encode/decode?
2. Is it just enough to replace "+" with "-" and "/" with " _" ?
3. When to do the padding "#"(adding/remove "#" to be considered )?

Answer (score 22):

### tl;dr

Use `basenc(1)` from `coreutils`:

```
$ printf "xs?>>>" | basenc --base64
eHM/Pj4+
$ printf "xs?>>>" | basenc --base64url
eHM_Pj4-
```

As with `base64(1)`, add the `-d` switch to decode.

### A bit of explanation

Recent versions of `coreutils` include `basenc(1)` which supports several different encodings. From its help screen:

```
--base64          same as 'base64' program (RFC4648 section 4)
--base64url       file- and url-safe base64 (RFC4648 section 5)
--base32          same as 'base32' program (RFC4648 section 6)
--base32hex       extended hex alphabet base32 (RFC4648 section 7)
--base16          hex encoding (RFC4648 section 8)
--base2msbf       bit string with most significant bit (msb) first
--base2lsbf       bit string with least significant bit (lsb) first
--z85             ascii85-like encoding (ZeroMQ spec:32/Z85);
                  when encoding, input length must be a multiple of 4;
                  when decoding, input length must be a multiple of 5
```

Here is a string that illustrates the difference:

```
s="xs?>>>"
```

As binary:

```
$ printf "%s" "$s" | xxd -b -c1 | cut -d' ' -f2 | nl
     1  01111000
     2  01110011
     3  00111111
     4  00111110
     5  00111110
     6  00111110
```

And as 6 bit blocks (as base64 reads the data):

```
$ printf "%s" "$s" | xxd -b -c1 | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d '\n' | fold -w6 | nl
     1  011110
     2  000111
     3  001100
     4  111111
     5  001111
     6  100011
     7  111000
     8  111110
```

Note that block 4 and block 8 map to `/` and `+` respectively ([Base64 table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table)):

Comment: Looks like `basenc` is not available anymore atlease as of ubuntu `20.04`

Comment: @Kamath: Which version of `coreutils` do you have installed (`apt-cache policy coreutils`)? `baseenc` is a recent addition (ca. 2020).

Answer (score 18):

This is the same suggestion as @jps but shorter. Also remember that `echo` by default always adds newline at the end, so when you want to encode it, you must add `-n`.

```
echo -n "Some_data_to_be_converted" | base64 | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '='
```

Decoding it back with bulit-in bash tools is more complicated as I didn't find an easy way to pad the string back with '=' so that the length will dividable by 4. Probably can be done with `awk` but I didn't dig deep enough. If you have local ruby it becomes trivial:

```
2.6.2 > require 'base64'
2.6.2 > Base64.urlsafe_encode64('test', padding: false)
 => "dGVzdA"
2.6.2 > Base64.urlsafe_decode64('dGVzdA')
 => "test"
```

Comment: The -n param for echo was the missing piece for me. Thank you :)

Comment: I took it as a challenge to come up with a bash or standard unix commands to pad the string back in order to decode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957358/how-to-encode-and-decode-data-in-base64-and-base64url-by-using-unix-commands/68921189#68921189

Answer (score 10):

Adding on to the [answer by Kaplan Ilya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957358/how-to-encode-and-decode-data-in-base64-and-base64url-by-using-unix-commands/62017480#62017480), here is a command using standard linux/unix commands that can decode `base64url`, including handling missing padding.

Note: some versions of `base64` can handle missing padding, such as Mac/BSD `base64 -D`. However, GNU `base64 -d` requires correct padding.

Also, I used the test string `~~~???` instead of the one in the original question `Some_data_to_be_converted`, so that it will generate `+`, `/`, `=` characters.

```sh
text='~~~???'

# encode base64
echo "$text" | base64
# fn5+Pz8/Cg==

# encode base64url
base64url=$( echo "$text" | base64 | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '=' )
echo "$base64url"
# fn5-Pz8_Cg

# decode base64url
echo "$base64url"==== | fold -w 4 | sed '$ d' | tr -d '\n' | tr '_-' '/+' | base64 -d
# ~~~???
```

Explanation of the decode base64url commands:

- `echo "$str"====` appends 4 equal signs
- `fold -w 4` split every 4 characters into separate lines
- `sed '$ d'` deletes the last line (the extraneous padding)
- `tr -d '\n'` joins all lines. Now the padding is correct.
- `tr '_-' '/+'` converts `_` to `/`, `-` to `+`.

(Side note: if you're wondering why not use `tr '-_' '+/'` since that would be in alphanumeric order, it's because that will result in `invalid option` because it thinks `-_` is an option. You could do `tr -- '-_' '+/'`, but it's easier just to swap the order.)

Answer (score 8):

If you already have a **base64 encoded** string you just need to replace "+" with "-" and "/" with " _" to get a **base64url encoded** string.
To achieve this, you can use the following command:

`echo Some_data_to_be_converted | base64 | sed 's/+/-/g; s,/,_,g'`

(you can try on [Execute Bash Shell Online](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php))

Base64 encoding maps the input bytes (8 bit) to a 6 bit representation. 4 base64 characters can encode 4*6=24 bits, which equals 3 bytes. Whenever the number of bytes in your input can't be divided by 3, padding is required according to the standard.

The padding character is `=`

As the `=`character is used for key-value pairs in URLs, you can't use it directly for padding if you intend to use the encoded value in an URL. You can either just ommit the padding, because most implementations will still work and just ignore the 2 or 4 unused bits on the end. Or, if the receiver really needs padding, you have to replace the `=` by it's URL safe representation `%3d`.